# cross compile azure iot sdk

Tags: cmake, debian, cross-compiling, beagleboard

I try to crosscompile the Azure IoT C SDK (https://github.com/azure/azure-iot-sdk-c) for a BeagleBoard Black.

I did setup a Debian GNU/Linux 8.7 (jessie) Machine and installed the toolchain as described here: http://exploringbeaglebone.com/chapter7/.

Then i followed the steps here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/doc/SDK_cross_compile_example.md and Created a Toolchain file:

```
INCLUDE(CMakeForceCompiler)

SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)     # this one is important
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)     # this one not so much

# this is the location of the amd64 toolchain targeting the Raspberry Pi
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf)

# search for programs in the build host directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

# for libraries and headers in the target directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

i call the Buildscript of the azure-sdk using:

```
./build.sh --toolchain-file toolchain-bb.cmake -cl --sysroot=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

The following Error Occures

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:136 (message):
Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
  system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_LIBRARIES
  OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:343 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
    /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:328 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  c-utility/CMakeLists.txt:141 (find_package)
```

i tried to install openssl using:

```
sudo apt-get install openssl:armhf
```

but the error remains, if i build the source for arm64 (using just the build.sh file of the azure-iot-sdk) everything works fine.

if i clone openssl and build it targeting arm i get the following error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:136 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
  system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_LIBRARIES) (found
  version "1.1.1")
```

Comment: When *cross-compile*, libraries are not searched under *host* directories. This is exactly what `SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)` means (see [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY.html)). And `apt-get` works with *host* packages.

Comment: @Tsyvarev if i clone openssl and build it for arm i get another error, I edited the Question

Comment: You need to install OpenSSL under sysroot, and possibly give a hint about its location to CMake (probably, suggested *OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR* would help).

Comment: If i add the directory to the cmake call -DOPENSSSL_ROOT_DIR the error remains. What do you mean under sysroot

Comment: By "installing under sysroot" I mean that installed files should be under directory you set as sysroot (`/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf`). With given toolchain you cannot ask CMake to search libraries outside of this directory. I just notice that when you build openssl for "targeting arm", CMake has found its headers, but libraries are still missed. What is location of the headers? (check value of *OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR* in CMake cache, `CMakeCache.txt`). Where (which directory) openssl libraries are installed?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Openssl present in your tool chain then you simply need to add a couple of additional lines to your cmake toolchain file. This will help cmake find your libraries and headers. Something like this:

`SET(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR /path/to/openssl/lib)
SET(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR /path/to/openssl/include/)`

If it is not present then you will need to cross compile openssl for your target and install it into your toolchain. Typically into `/<sysroot>/usr/lib` and `/<sysroot>/usr/include`.

Alternatively if openssl is on your device but not in your toolchain then you can simply copy it from the device. There is an example of copying dependencies to the toolchain in the Raspberry Pi demo here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/doc/SDK_cross_compile_example.md